# How to use a web API with Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, api, django-views

There is this web api for weather: http://openweathermap.org/current

Everytime I try to research how to use web APIs with Django, I get redirected to REST - isn't that for building an API? I don't want to do that.

If I simply want to learn about using APIs with Django, where should I go?

I'm not sure how to set it up within the view.

I tried:

```
from urllib2 import Request
```

and then

```
r = Request('http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip={0},us&appid=0b7f3cd153bc12d3accb83f9682bccbb'.format(zipcode))
json_object = r.read()
```

That didn't seem to work though.

Comment: REST is a kind of api.  You can make a REST api and you can use a REST api.

Comment: also if you are grabbing data please look into the documentation for deserializer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
import urllib2
url = 'http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip={0},us&appid=0b7f3cd153bc12d3accb83f9682bccbb'.format(zipcode) # if zipcode is defined
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
response.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

By Using API you mean sending GET, POST, PUT etc. requests to some server. For that you can use python's `requests` module. Like this:

```
### Installation
pip install requests

### Usage
import requests
url = 'http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip={0},us&appid=0b7f3cd153bc12d3accb83f9682bccbb'.format(zipcode)
req = requests.get(url)

### if json response is coming
response = req.json()

### else
response = req.content
```

More information at [Python Requests Documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)